# How to measure TTFB with Puppeteer?

Tags: puppeteer

Is it possible to calculate the [TTFB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_to_first_byte) with Puppeteer?

I couldn't find anything in their docs.

I currently have this code:

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch(launchOptions);
const page = await browser.newPage();
const response = await page.goto(url);
const { status } = response;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I solved it:

```js
const browser = await puppeteer.launch(launchOptions);
const page = await browser.newPage();
await page.goto(url);
const navigationTimingJson = await page.evaluate(() =>
  JSON.stringify(performance.getEntriesByType("navigation"))
);
const [navigationTiming] = JSON.parse(navigationTimingJson)
const TTFB = navigationTiming.responseStart - navigationTiming.requestStart;
```

Answer (score 0):

This might do what you want:

```
let start = new Date()
page.once('response', () => console.log(new Date() - start))
await page.goto(url)
```

Comment: I may be wrong, but doesn't this event fire when the whole response is received? and not just the first byte?

Comment: I don't think so. It returns a promise and you have to await to get the full body.

Comment: Do you have any idea why it's logging smaller values than `time_starttransfer` ? Your way outputs around 700 ms, but `time_starttransfer` outputs around 1400ms. I'm trying to get reliable values.

Comment: I get `time_starttransfer` value through a cURL request.

Comment: I don't really know anything about that, sorry. Maybe because of h2/h3?

Answer (score -1):

You can try using `page.metrics()`

More info here: https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v13.1.3&show=api-pagemetrics

Comment: The link returns Not Found. Also, please provide a working snippet here.

Comment: On a second thought, actually the metrics does not help at all with TTFB. Please update your answer.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).